# Do you have to do a full package/model build when you rename custom data entity or change some metadata properties?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-365-operations, d3fo, data-entities

I have to rename some custom made data entities.

However every time after renaming an entity and changing some of the metadata properties such as data management staging table, public collection name and public entity name, it gives below error on project rebuild. Do I really need to keep rebuilding my entire model/package just to rename a data entity or change some metadata properties?

> Error     at Dynamics.AX.Application.DmfDataPopulation.syncEntityCreate(DictDataEntity dictDataEntity, Boolean useTargetEntityName)           0
>
> Error      Infolog diagnostic message: 'Cannot create a record in Entity (DMFEntity). Entity: Plans, xPlannedOrdersEntityStaging.          0
>
> Error      at Microsoft.Dynamics.Ax.Xpp.Common.Insert()            0
>
> Error      at Dynamics.AX.Application.DmfDataPopulation.syncEntityUpdate(DMFEntity _dmfEntity, DictDataEntity _dictDataEntity)         0
>
> Error      at Dynamics.AX.Application.DmfDataPopulation.syncEntityUpdate(DMFEntity _dmfEntity, DictDataEntity _dictDataEntity, Boolean _useTargetEntityName, Boolean @_useTargetEntityName_IsDefaultSet) in xppSource://Source/ApplicationFoundation\AxClass_DmfDataPopulation.xpp:line 1153           0
>
> Error      at Dynamics.AX.Application.DmfDataPopulation.`syncEntityMetadata(StringCollection dataEntityViewCollection, StringCollection compositeEntityList) in xppSource://Source/ApplicationFoundation\AxClass_DmfDataPopulation.xpp:line 996.' on category 'Error'.         0
>
> Error      at Dynamics.AX.Application.DMFEntity.insert()           0
>
> Error      at Dynamics.AX.Application.DmfDataPopulation.syncEntityCreate(DictDataEntity dictDataEntity, Boolean useTargetEntityName, Boolean @useTargetEntityName_IsDefaultSet) in xppSource://Source/ApplicationFoundation\AxClass_DmfDataPopulation.xpp:line 1104            0
>
> Error      Database synchronization failed. You may have to do a full build of the package 'xTools' and all of its dependent packages.         0
>
> Error      at Microsoft.Dynamics.Ax.MSIL.cqlCursorIL.insert(IntPtr table)
>   0
>
> Error      The record already exists.' on category 'Error'.            0
>
> Error      at Microsoft.Dynamics.Ax.Xpp.NativeCommonImplementation.Insert()            0
>
> Error      Infolog diagnostic message: 'Error synching entity metadata for entity - xPlannedOrdersEntity. Message -    at Microsoft.Dynamics.Ax.MSIL.Interop.throwException(Int32 ExceptionValue, interpret* ip)           0
>
> Error      at Dynamics.AX.Application.DMFEntity.`insert() in xppSource://Source/ApplicationFoundation\AxTable_DMFEntity.xpp:line 433           0

Answer (score 1):

from the community forum:

1. Delete the entities from Entity list in D365FO
2. Rename
3. Build and sync your model. I think it's good to build the whole model after renaming objects. Renaming should not be very common so not too much extra work for you
4. Refresh entity list